# Flexible grid on JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

Do you know some plugin for the flexible grid on JS (on jquery, extjs or others libraries)

**Requirements for grid**:

- easily add an additional cell (for new column);
- storing in one field two variables;
- input data json.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using two, however I'm not sure if they match your needs. They still can be a good starting point:

1. jqGrid - http://www.trirand.com/blog/
2. Kendo UI Grid - http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html - thay also have a GPL licence, not sure if suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

Look at: http://a-web.me/controls.html#sheet

Lightweight and powerful framework